# How do I add images to custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, custom, image

I need to add an extra, static image in the page header. Right after the logo.

My child theme directory structure in
`[magento project root]/app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme/`

```
  ├── Magento_Theme
  │   └── templates
  │       └── html
  │           └── header
  │               └── logo.phtml
  │               
  ├── media
  │   └── preview.png
  ├── registration.php
  ├── theme.xml
  └── web
      └── images
          ├── logo.png
          └── CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png
```

The `CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png` is missing in the static files, the rest works fine.

The symlinks to images are being generated in a static folder `[magento project root]/pub/static/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme/my_language/images/`. My custom `logo.png` appears there along with `loader-1.gif` which I assume comes from the parent theme. Unfortunately my custom image `CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png` is not there.

In my modified `Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml` I have the line `echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png')` that also works as expected, printing the path to the generated static folder.

What do I miss here? Do I need to declare the `CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It worked!
I don't know what I did that I haven't done before but the CUSTOM_TAGLINE.png  symlink appeared along with few other files.
If you have similar problems just make sure to cache:flush and grunt refresh (if you use grunt). I suspect that was one of those.